# Can latex use function like excel?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{SUM}
\hline
2 & 3 & 5
\end{tabular}
```

But, if I change C1 or C2, I have to change SUM manually.
In excel, I can use function like `=C1+C2`, then SUM will update automatically when C1 or C2 changed.
Can latex do that?

Comment: `pgfplotstable` could probably do this.

Comment: Could you give an example? @Manuel

Comment: No, I don't know how it works, I only know of its existence.

Comment: [`spreadtab`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab)

Comment: @DaiBowen, please convert your comment to answer!

Comment: @DaiBowen I didn't want to 'steal' your answer. Please post an answer (feel free to copy my code), and I will delete mine. I've just got the impression that you love terse answers and therefore wouldn't expand your comment, but thought that an example showing working code would be helpful.

Comment: I strongly feel that if you need these capabilities then your LaTeX document (or at least the table part) should be automatically generated by a separate tool, regardless of the existence of the spreadtab package.

Comment: @gernot not to worry I have no real experience of `spreadtab` just knowledge that it does Excel type functions. I was not at a computer to provide any MWE so commenting seemed the best way to give the OP the necessary information (I probably should have invited somebody else to write a proper answer in this case). I normally do follow up on request to convert comments to answers though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just an advertiser for @DaiBowen's suggestion: The first example of the [`spreadtab` Manual](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/spreadtab/spreadtab_doc_en.pdf) (page 2) addresses your question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rr|r}}
   22    &    54    & a1+b1 \\
   43    &    65    & a2+b2 \\
   49    &    37    & a3+b3 \\
\hline
a1+a2+a3 & b1+b2+b3 & a4+b4
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this answer, i was looking for this type of functionality.